# How to increase first time loading speed of Magento 2 site?

Tags: magento2

I have applied many many ways but some minor increased speed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got another solution,

> If your site on production environment then and you can use **"CDN
>   Server"** and setup it with your URL with CDN URL Then you will get
>   definitely improve your site speed.
>
> More info ["CDN server"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network).
>
> I hope my answer will help you.

Thanks,

Comment: there is 100% impossible to make first load faster. you can use whatever technology you can - there are none to help you. only when you get remote cached and local browser cached - then page will load fast. you still need sometime to load content from CDN end point.

Answer (score 0):

The best and easy way to speed up the magneto website is page cache. But beside page cache, you can do the following to improve server response.

1. Inspect every installed 3rd-party extension, and disable useless extensions on your website
2. Choose the fastest hosting you can afford
3. Turn Production Mode On
4. Never Use JS Bundling
   [image]
5. Enable CSS/JS Minification
   [image]
6. Last and most importantly, enable profiler and check all the files (.phtml) and events, check which are taking more time to execute. And remember even 0.5 sec for a file or event is also huge time for a single file/event.

Comment: I have already applied the same configuration settings, but still, the same issue was there.

But now I got a solution for it.

My pro server link set on CDN server using this solution I got increased my web page speed.

Comment: I need another solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have an index load time of around 2.5 seconds while running in DEVELOPER mode;

Assuming a CPANEL/APACHE server

1) Setup VARNISH Cache

2) Setup MEMCACHED

3) Setup ENGINTRON

4) I dont do this, but Cloud fronting speeds it up

5) Setup APACHE and PHP speed boosters.  Here is my EasyApache 4 config for APACHE and PHP;

Apache 2.4
config

config-runtime
mod_allowmethods
mod_asis
mod_authn_dbd
mod_authn_dbm
mod_authn_socache
mod_bwlimited
mod_cache
mod_cache_disk
mod_cache_socache
mod_cgid
mod_dbd
mod_env
mod_expires
mod_file_cache
mod_mpm_worker
mod_proxy
mod_proxy_fcgi
mod_proxy_http
mod_proxy_wstunnel
mod_socache_memcache
mod_ssl
mod_version
tools

PHP 7.2

libc-client
pear
php-bcmath
php-cli
php-common
php-curl
php-devel
php-fileinfo
php-fpm
php-ftp
php-gd
php-iconv
php-imap
php-intl
php-litespeed
php-mbstring
php-mysqlnd
php-opcache
php-pdo
php-posix
php-soap
php-xml
php-xmlrpc
php-zip
runtime

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Do you have any other solution?

Comment: I have already applied the same configuration settings, but still, the same issue was there. But now I got a solution for it. My pro server link set on CDN server using this solution I got increased my web page speed.

Comment: CDN is point 4 above and is part of the solution.  You also did well to set all of the above up so quickly.  Took me a week to configure, tweak the settings and test everything.  Glad that you have it sorted out